# Pandas placing element in wrong location

Tags: python, pandas

So I am trying to get api data for stocks and have some text documents as stand in json files to test it.

This is the code I'm using to open the text file and read it as a json.

```
file = open(os.path.join('macd.txt'), "r")

df_macd = pd.read_json(file)
```

For some reason Pandas has put the very first item (the ticker/symbol) in the json in the middle of the dataframe?

Picture of text file used and debug of dataframe:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG9AW.jpg

even if I do:

```
df_macd = df_macd['Technical Analysis: MACD']
```

It's still there.

Comment: Please illustrate your scenario with an minimal example using a dataframe as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first key in your JSON under "Meta Data" reads "1: Symbol".

Pandas has taken the inner keys in the JSON as row index. Indices are sorted in ascending form.

So, after 1999-XX-XX the above mentioned key comes i.e. "1: Symbol".

You might notice that after 2XXX-XX-XX the key "2: Indicator" arrives.